# Templates inside templates. Specializing a template class inside a template function

Tags: c++, templates, stl

In the following example, I want to get a stl container (either list or unordered_set) using the template function f. I know that the stl container will contain integers.

I tried to use partial template template specialization but it was not working.

How do I achieve what I want?

The code above doesn't compile obviously.

```
#include <list>
#include <unordered_set>

template <typename T, template C<T>>
C<T> f()
{
    C<T> d;
    d.insert(1);
    return d;
}

int main()
{
    auto l = f<int, std::list<int>>();
    auto s = f<int, std::unordered_set>();

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You're going to have a problem at least in that `std::list` doesn't take `insert` the same way `std::unordered_set` does. The former requires a position; the latter does not.

That aside, I can make it compile and execute with (don't forget you need to instantiate the template):

```
template <typename T, typename C>
C f()
{
    C d;
    d.insert(1);
    return d;
}

template std::unordered_set<int> f<int, std::unordered_set<int>>();
```

But you won't be able to use a list this way.

Is this sort of thing acceptable to you? If not, I think you need to clarify your question more as to what you want.

Comment: Can you explain the last line please?

Comment: The last line of the code, or the last line of the answer?

Comment: The last line of the code, i don't really understand it.

Comment: You have to instantiate a function template to each type. The line `template std::unordered_set<int> f<int, std::unordered_set<int>>();` instantiates a function template for `f` to the types `int` and `std::unordered_set<int>`. This specification appears in angle brackets (`<` and `>`) after `f` and before the parentheses. Notice that if you replace `std::unordered_set<int>` by `C` and `int` by `T` you get the template in the first two lines. -- which, by the by, makes me realize I copied & pasted the first two lines wrong so I'll fix, sorry.

Comment: Ok, so it is a function template specialization for `std::unordered_set`? Also if I call it using an `std::unordered_set`, I will get an error from the liker because you have not defined its body, right?

Comment: Oh ok, I got it, it tells the compiler to instantiate the function when `T = int` and `C = std::unordered_set`. Thank you.

Comment: Technically `C = std::unordered_set<int>` but yes. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply create a set of overloaded functions to insert in the container-specific ways you need.

```
template <typename T>
void f_impl(std::unordered_set<T> & container)
{
    container.insert(1);
}

template <typename T>
void f_impl(std::list<T> & container)
{
    container.push_back(1);
}

template <typename T, template<class...> class C>
C<T> f()
{
    C<T> d;
    f_impl(d);
    return d;
}
```

then you can do:

```
auto c1 = f<int, std::unordered_set>();
auto c2 = f<int, std::list>();
```

to your heart's delight.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.

This worked for me. I put it together from the answers you guys posted.

The problem I wanted was much simpler. I wanted to be able to specialize an STL container inside a template function. Obviously, the insert functions are different but I just removed that since I didn't need to insert. I just needed to create the container.

```
#include <list>
#include <unordered_set>

template <template <class...> class C>
C<int> f()
{
    C<int> d;
    return d;
}

int main()
{
    auto l = f<std::list>();
    auto s = f<std::unordered_set>();

    return 0;
}
```